# How do I check if user can login to CloudKit?

Tags: ios, icloud, ios8, icloud-api, cloudkit

Can I use the same way I check for iCloud availability or is there some other way of checking for CloudKit availability?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `CKContainer` class has a method called `accountStatusWithCompletionHandler:` that's designed for this purpose. Call it and check for `CKAccountStatusAvailable`. You'll still need to listen for `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification` in case the status changes.

Comment: What if user if offline, but logged in to iCloud. Will it work and return CKAccountStatusAvailable?

Comment: It should. Offline, the phone still knows about the account.